# Getting the value of select box using event target value

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I'm a Javascript beginner, learning by doing. Here I have a select box where it has options of different cars. I can get this working easily by doing like this: `var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;` but I want to do it using ( `event.target` ). Am I doing it wrong ?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(event)">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>                                                
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").event.target.value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

> 3.html:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined at myFunction (3.html:19) at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: I ran your code and don't see a problem with it. Why are you trying to use event.target instead of just using value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm getting this error : 3.html:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
    at myFunction (3.html:19)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this instead.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.target;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(event)">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>                                                
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: it should not print 'true', should print what ever user chooses from list